# Python @property same id as field returned by it

Tags: python, properties

I made this simple snippet to understand properties better:

```
class foo:
def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

@property
def val(self):
    return self._val

@val.setter
def val(self, value):
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError("Value has to be larger than 0")
    else:
        self._val = value

  
f1 = foo(2)
print(id(f1._val) == id(f1.val)) #print true
```

Right now I undestand less than before I wrote that code. How is it, that both `f1._val` and `f1.val` are the same object? Is it some magic done in backstage? Also, why `type(f1.val)` is `int` when it is a `function`?

Another thing is that I though to change both `val` functions (one decorated by `@property`, second by `@val.setter`) to `return self.val` not `return self._val`. When trying to instantiate object I got:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

What is quite obvious as I return pointer to function (not sure if pointer is proper in this context?) with no condition. But here, how my first snippet worked fine even though both `self._val` and `self.val` are same object?

Comment: "How is it, that both `f1._val` and `f1.val` are the same object?" Because the `val` property getter simply returns `self._val`... I'm not sure what it is that you don't understand. Do you understand taht when you do `f1.val` it *calls* the getter and evaluates to that value?

Comment: `foo.val` is *not a function any more*. It is a `property`. `property` objects implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Basically, a descriptor on some class, `MyClass.some_desriptor` can define a `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__` method.  When you create an instance, `myinstance = MyClass()` then that descriptors `__get__`, `__set__`, and `__delete__` methods will be called for `myinstance.my_descriptor`, `myinstance.my_desriptor = foo`, and `del myinstance.my_descriptor` respectively

Comment: When there is another method defined in the class, e.g. `func` that returns an `int`, and I would instantiate class in the very same way `type(f1.func)` is method, while `type(f1.func())` is int. It makes sense to me. Then `type(f1.val())` should also be an int, while `type(f1.val)` should be a method as far as I understand (I may be wrong however)

Comment: **it isn't a method, it is a `property` object*. Do you understand what `@property` is doing? Do you know what decorators are? I explained descriptors above, `property` is *also* a decorator, but that is mostly syntactic suguar. Basically `@property def val(self): ...` is equivalent to `def val(self): ...` then `val = property(val)`. So the `val` attribute on the class *is not longer a function/method*. It is a `property` descriptor. Note, *functions are also descriptors*, that is how they "magically" provide the instance as the first argument

Comment: Yes, yes, thank you. My comment was published before webpage had refreshed and I saw your second comment.

Comment: A `function` is *also* a descriptor, so (for instance) what you get when you use either `foo.__init__` or `foo().__init__` is defined by `function.__get__`, just as what you get from either `foo.val` or `foo().val` is defined by `property.__get__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `val` is a descriptor as described in [3.3.2.2. Implementing Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). With a descriptor, access to a variable is replaced with calls to its `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__` methods. The `property` function is a shortcut to creating descriptors. Since "property" and "descriptor" amount to the same thing, I don't know why two different names are used.

With

```
@property
def val(self):
    return self._val
```

`val` is bound to an object whose `__get__` executes the body of the function. It gets the local variable `_val`.

With

```
@val.setter
def val(self, value):
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError("Value has to be larger than 0")
    else:
        self._val = value
```

The object bound to `val` is updated so that its `__set__` executes the body of the function, setting `_val`.

When python executes `f1.val`, it gets the object referenced by "val" but before returning, it checks to see if the object has a `__get__`. If so, instead of returning the object, it calls `__get__` and uses its return. In your case, "_val" is returned, so naturally they are equal.

If you change your property function to get "val" instead of "_val", python still follows the same rule. "val" is a descriptor so its `__get__` is called, which tries to get "val" again, but its a descriptor ... and on and on.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it, that both f1._val and f1.val are the same object?

Because you are setting them to the same object in your code. You take your value, in this case `2` and assign it to both `self.val` & `self._val`

What you did is the equivalent of

`a = 2`

`b = 2`

`a == b`

`True`

> Also, why type(f1.val) is int when it is a function?

When using the `@property` decorator, the method no longer is callable. You can think of it almost like an attribute.